# Как сравнить два объекта в Python?

Tags: python

Допустим, равны ли два объекта по каким-то полям или нет?

Comment: @Nikitc, все таки класса или объекта?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам сюда: [`docs.python.2:object.__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Для того чтобы для работали операторы сравнения, в классе нужно реализовать соответствующий метод:

```
object.__lt__(self, other) # < 
object.__le__(self, other) # <=
object.__eq__(self, other) # == 
object.__ne__(self, other) # !=
object.__gt__(self, other) # >
object.__ge__(self, other) # >=
```

к примеру:

```
class MyComparableClass:
  def __init__(self, val):
     self.val = val
  def __eq__(self, other):
     return self.val == other.val
  def __ne__(self, other):
     return self.val != other.val
  def __lt__(self, other):
     return self.val < other.val

print(MyComparableClass(1) == MyComparableClass(2))  # False
print(MyComparableClass(1) < MyComparableClass(2))  # True
print(MyComparableClass(1) > MyComparableClass(2))  # False
print(MyComparableClass(1) >= MyComparableClass(2))  # TypeError: unorderable types
```

Comment: требует реализовать метод  __hash__

Comment: кто требует? зачем требует?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите сравнить объект вашего класса, используя стандартные операторы сравнения вам нужно будет определить [специальный метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433372/183327) для каждого. Но, начиная с **версии python 2.7** можно использовать [**`total_odering`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) декоратора. Все, что вам нужно, это `__eq __ ()` и один метод сравнения `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, или `__ge__`.

---

К примеру:

```
>>> from functools import total_ordering
>>> import math
>>> @total_ordering
... class Point:
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...          self.x = x
...          self.y = y
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return math.hypot(self.x, self.y) == math.hypot(other.x, other.y)
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         return math.hypot(self.x, self.y) > math.hypot(other.x, other.y)
... 
>>> p1 = Point(2,3)
>>> p2 = Point(4,5)
>>> p1 < p2
True
>>> p1 >= p2
False
```